# How can I return the fetch API results from a function?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to return fetch API result from a function. but I get undefined and that function doesn't return me fetched data :

```js
function func() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => (json.results))
}

let users = func()

console.log(users);
```

Comment: use async then await

Comment: @UllasHunka you have not any idea without async/wait ? because I don't want to get that result inside a function. maybe it's a class method !

Answer (score 19):

`Fetch` is asynchronous and returns a promise. There is no way to take the data returned by fetch and access it synchronously. And it can't return `users` because the function needs to return synchronously but the data for `users` won't be available. The function returns before Fetch has a response from the url. That's okay, that's how everything is done and it all still works.

The most flexible way to handle this is to just return the promise from the function. Then you can use `then()` on the result of the promise and do anything you need to do there:

```
function func(url) {
    return fetch(url)  // return this promise
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => (json.results))
}

func('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
.then(users => console.log(users))  // call `then()` on the returned promise to access users
.catch(err => /* handle errors */)
```

Comment: thank you so much for this well explained answer and a very useful code snippet as well!

Answer (score 1):

An example of fetch can be as follow:

```
loadJSON('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10');
async function loadJSON(fname) {
    var response = await fetch(fname)
    var j =  await response.json()
    document.getElementById('jsondemo1').value = j.name
    document.getElementById('jsondemo2').value = j.year
}
```

Without async and await:

```
fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log('success:', result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error:', error));
```

Comment: Can I use that result without any functions ?! maybe I want to use that in a constructor method in a class for example

Comment: Updated the answer have a look

Comment: I see, consider it: for example I have a public fetch_data function and I want to use that in all parts of application. sometimes I want to fetch api in functions or outside of functions and I can't use async/await. Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

As this call is asynchronous `users` is `undefined` when you are logging this as a response has not been received by the server you need to do the following. You can add `then` to your `func` call which will then log users when a response has been received.

```js
function func(url) {
    return fetch(url)  // return this promise
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => (json.results))
}

func('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
.then(users => console.log(users))
```

Comment: The variable `Users` can be ,oved to the function block, then the assignment can be made, and the function can then return the variable. One less global-ish variable :-)

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you are returning a value in your function.
Your function will evaluate to undefined if a value is not returned.

Return the result of your fetch call (ie: json.results), and tell us what happens.

Comment: this is not the reason why, it is because the response has not been received from the api

Comment: I don't think that is the case. `then` is a promise syntax, and the second `then` call executes after the promise has been resolved or rejected, in which case, the error would be forwarded to a catch block.

Comment: I think it is :-) that function is returning a value - there is an implicit return from arrow functions written like this - bit of reading here for you - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: he can try to log the response of the second then block in the function to try this out.  Log the results of the call inside the function.

Comment: Okay, let's try this. Initialize a variable as undefined. Then in the second then block, assign the results of the call to the undefined variable, then return the variable in the main function scope. It just might be a scope problem.

Comment: @Nnanyielugo that doesn't work, the function returns synchronously, so it will return the undefined value before it has been set in the `then()`.