# How to use response from fetch() api

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch

How to use response from fetch api?

i try to `return` my response, but when i try to print this values in my function, i get `undefined`,
can someone tell me how to use this response in different function?

my response is an json of nested objects

```
  async fetchData() {
    const url = `...`;

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            //
        })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then(response => {;
        console.log(response) //correct response
        return response;
      })

  }

  async getDataFromFetchApi() {
      const data= await this.fetchData();
      console.log(data); // undefined

      if(data != undefined){
        throw new BadRequestException();
     }

      return data;   
  }
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return the fetch API results form a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417108/how-can-i-return-the-fetch-api-results-form-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line, an `async` function must `return` a promise to work correctly. `fetchData` has no return value. The `return response` is inside of a `.then`, and doesn't apply to the `fetchData` function itself.

For the above code, the fewest modifications is simply to `return fetch(...)` in your `fetchData` function, like this:

```
async fetchData() {
  const url = `...`;

  return fetch(/* ... */)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response) //correct response
      return response;
    })

}
```

Alternatively you could use the `async/await` syntax for all it's worth, and get rid of your `.then`s, like this:

```
async fetchData() {
  const url = `...`;

  const resp = await fetch(/* ... */);
  const json = await resp.json();
  console.log(json);
  return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return data in the scope of `fetchData` function:

```js
async fetchData() {
    const url = `...`;

    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            //...
        })
    });

    return response;
}
```