# How to access async fetched API data syncronously as a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

My goal is to access the API data from a fetch, and use it outside the function it was called in.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. If I can never use the data from an async function outside of the function, does that mean that I can only use the data inside getWeatherData if I write more code inside getWeatherData? I plan to make other API calls, and I imagine that continuously nesting async functions to access data is not the right way to go about this.

Advice on how to resolve this is greatly appreciated!

[image: Promise pending when expected javascript object]

I have tried the fix from this question [How can I return the fetch API results from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417108/how-can-i-return-the-fetch-api-results-from-a-function), and tried returning data without JSON.stringify or JSON.parse as well as adding await to those steps.

Comment: *How to access async fetched API data syncronously* - you can't

Comment: why do you want it synchronously? that promise could easily take 200ms.. this means the browser tab hanging for that long, OR `let weather_today=await getWeatherData()` should work